# Compressing/Mapping voltage range

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

I am looking to control an voltage regulating IC, MIC2288, which is attached to a support circuit, as per the picture below.

[image]

The idea is to regulate the output of this circuit via a DAC, and connect it to code.
This is shown in the pink box on the circuit diagram. Previously I used a constant 5V source instead of a DAC and regulated the voltage at FB with a potentiometer, but it seems that the IC didn't like being connected directly to another resistor network, hence the diode.

The problem I am having is mapping the 0-5V of the DAC to the 1.215-1.265V range that the IC should receive on the FB (feedback) pin. They can be mapped either directly or inversely (aka 0v can be either 1.265 or 1.215), but I am struggling to find a method of shrinking the range and upping the bias point, and have struggled to understand the circuits I have found.

I attempted to follow the Texas Instruments [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf), but it seems that following the recommendation of "positive b and positive m" led to a negative resistor value.

Advice on what kinds of circuits can achieve this would be appreciated, whether it can be done with one based on operational amplifiers or not.

Comment: The regulatur tires to hold the voltage at "FB" in a certain range (around 1.24V apparently). If you just connect 5V there, the regulator can't reculate anymore. What you need to do is not applying a voltage to FB but influence the feedback...

Comment: Why are you specifying the output voltage so precisely then putting a PN diode in series with it? You will not get precise control unless you use measure the actual output voltage and create a feedback loop to control the DAC.

Comment: This is a common problem. While the simple solution (add a third leg to the voltage divider that goes to your DAC) will work, you might be interested in taking a look at a white paper on the problem to see other solutions: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/8/818.html

Comment: Also you're misunderstanding the feedback voltage. It's not a range of values, it's a simple number. The range you're quoting is probably the tolerance (each chip has a value in that range that depends on manufacturing, temperature, aging, etc).

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work. The feedback pin is called "feedback" for a reason: It allows the IC to see the output voltage it's generating so that it can regulate it (react to it being too low or too high). The feedback voltage needs to depend linearly on the output voltage for this to work.

If you just connect a fixed voltage source to the feedback input, the IC can't see its own output voltage anymore, so it's just flying blind and will be unable to keep a constant output voltage.

The feedback mechanism works like this: The IC tries to always keep a constant voltage at its feedback pin. If the voltage at the pin is too high, it lowers the output voltage. If it's too low, it raises the output voltage. Since the feedback voltage is a fraction of the output voltage (set via the voltage divider), the output voltage will be a fixed multiple of the feedback voltage.

If you want to influence the regulator via a DAC, you have to *subtract* a voltage from the feedback pin while leaving the actual feedback mechanism intact, not just "override" the feedback voltage. You can do this by injecting a (negative) current into the feedback network, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR9Fxy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

VCCS1 is a voltage-controlled current source, which means that varying the voltage at the CTRL net varies the current being pulled from the FB net. This will increase the output voltage by **dV = Ictrl * (Rfb1 | Rfb2)**, with little error.

There are lots of ways to build such a voltage-controlled current source; I'm sure you'll find one that suits your needs.

Comment: Apologies for a late reply. Increasing the current output by VCCS1 then results in more current flowing out of the FB pin? Or simply reduce the net current flowing through Rfb2 so that the FB pin sees less voltage?

Comment: Neither of the two. There is no current flowing into or out of the FB pin. The current sunk by VCCS1 is supplied through Rfb1 (from the output). This means that the voltage drop across Rfb1 increases linearly with the current sunk by VCCS1. Since V(OUT)=V(FB)+I(VCCS1)\*Rfb1, and V(FB) is held constant by the chip, the output voltage also increases linearly with increasing VCCS1 current. (The chip varies the output voltage so that V(FB) always stays the same.)